# Dafny: Help proper invariant, decreases statement

Tags: functional-programming, dafny

Can anyone help me with what's wrong here.
I get the below error when verifying this program.

I have tried various ways but it never passess the verification. Please help.

```
method Main() {
     var a:int := 0;
     var b:int := -1;
     var c:int := 0;
     var i:int := 100;
     while (a!=b)
     invariant 0<=c<i
     decreases i-c
     {
         b := a;
       c := c+1;
         if (c < i) {
           a := a+1;
         }
     }
    print "Eureka";
}
```

.............

```
stdin.dfy(7,19): Error BP5005: This loop invariant might not be maintained by the loop.
Execution trace:
    (0,0): anon0
    stdin.dfy(6,6): anon12_LoopHead
    (0,0): anon12_LoopBody
    stdin.dfy(6,6): anon13_Else
    stdin.dfy(6,6): anon15_Else
    (0,0): anon16_Else
    (0,0): anon10

Dafny program verifier finished with 1 verified, 1 error
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding "invariant c == i ==> b == a;" fixed it. As dafny was not able to link between c,i to b,a.

```
method Main() {
     var a:int := 0;
     var b:int := -1;
     var c:int := 0;
     var i:int := 100;
     while (a!=b)
     invariant 0<=c<=i
     invariant c == i ==> b == a;
     decreases i-c
     {
         b := a;
         c := c+1;
         if (c < i) {
           a := a+1;
         }
     }
    print "Eureka";
}
```